# Crossover different length genotypes

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, crossover

E.g. I have two random representatives

> 1 6 8 9 0 3 4 7 5

and

> 3 6 5 7 8 5

What are the ways to crossover them?

Add some empty numbers (or operations or sth) on the end of every genotype so they will have the same size?

> 3 6 5 7 8 5 -1 -1 -1

where -1 means nothing?

Or copy few number from first genotype and some from second?

What is the way you use?

Comment: Difficult to answer because what you need to do is largely problem dependent. You need to figure out what makes the most sense to do for your specific problem. If a specific number in the same position, regardless of the amount of numbers in total, always means / does the exact same thing (but not the same as the same number in a different position), what you suggested would work just fine. If not, you may want to consider doing a more complex cross-over.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you already have variable length chromosomes, then it shouldnt matter how you do it, you just need to select a crossover point for each of them, and then crossover as normal.

For example using your chromosomes, I have selected two points (.) at random:

```
1 6 8 9.0 3 4 7 5
3 6.5 7 8 5
```

With resulting chromosomes:

```
1 6 8 9.5 7 8 5
3 6.0 3 4 7 5
```